# Command \beamer@@tmpop@footline@miniframes theme already defined

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

How can I solve this problem in the bellow structure?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{footline=institutetitle}{beamerouterthememiniframes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\author[ggg]{ggg}
\institute[ddd]{ggg}
\date{\today}
%\useoutertheme[footline=institutetitle]{miniframes}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\frame{Hello}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the Ilmenau theme, you could redefine the footline using the code from the `institutetitle` footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute%
      \ifbeamertemplateempty{page number in head/foot}{}{\qquad}%
      \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%      
      }%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\usefonttheme{serif}
\author[aaa]{aaa}
\institute[iii]{iii}
\title[ttt]{ttt}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\frame{Hello}  
\end{document}
```

[image]